# what Adobe flash player runtime and API build top on?

Tags: flash

I wanna know how Adobe engineers build and extend flash player runtime and API?
you know , the AS3 just is a language for using the Flash Player API and it is not build on the AS3 language so how and what language  Adobe folks use to  build these APIs?

this question can be use for Java too?

I''l really appreciate .

BR
Farid Valipour

Answer (score 0):

The majority of desktop software that's intended to be compiled for different platforms and where high performance is critical is written in C/C++.

You'll find that's the case with the Flash Player (and most probably the JRE too).

See: http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash